# UIButton over an UIImageView via storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to create my view as below:
[image]

For which i have figured out i need an `UIImageView` to display the default profile pic and a `UIButton` with an image of camera over the `UIImageView`. I added an `UIButton` over the `UIImageView`, but when i run my code it is not visible. I tried changing the background color and added some text on the `UIButton` but the `UIButton` is not displayed. I have already gone through similar questions but most of them were solved by adding the code for `UIButton` and `UIImageView` and not via storyboard. Can someone point out where i am going wrong.
Also any other suggestions to make similar view are appreciated. The one i can think of is to use and `UIImageView` instead of `UIButton` and enable it's user interaction. But that isn't much different than using `UIButton`.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you added both `UIImageView` and `UIButton` in storyboard?

Comment: are you using auto-layout or any other constraints? Or try to increase the width of uibutton for just checking this is visible or not inside complete uiview.

Comment: @Dev.RK - Yes i am using auto-layout, and the `UIButton` is visible when i move it out of the `UIImageView`

Comment: @TKutal adjust your button constraints you have added. This will help you. Due to some constraints your button is not visible inside the uiwindow or uiview.

Comment: Do one thing take whole the button and set its Background image then also set one image to button. and set image content inset in button. No need of imageView only take button

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code :

```
[btn.superView bringSubViewToFront :btn];
```

Write above line of code at the end of `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` mathod.

Comment: I have updated my answer plz check and if not work then upload image of your view's stack of storyboard file.

Comment: Adding constraints to the button helped. I think `bringSubViewToFront` will help if i add the button via code. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check in document outline in storyboard and check view's stack.button should be above imageView(below in document outline). if not then change position by simple drag and drop. Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to drag the `button` from the document outline as it comes after the `ImageView`. Check the images given. [image: Check the button position in the document outline]